# How to add button at top of Layered navigation Filter from custom module?

Tags: magento2, blocks, layered-navigation, phtml

I have a phtml that contain button like this in my custom module :

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/templates/button.phtml**

```
<button> <span> <?= __('New Button') ?> </span> </button>
```

i want to add this phtml in top of layered navigation filter, so it will look like this:

[image]

How can i do this using custom module, not from theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cerate the custom module and after move the button

**/Mage/Mohit/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mage_Mohit',
    __DIR__
);
```

**/Mage/Mohit/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © EAdesign by Eco Active S.R.L.,All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mage_Mohit" setup_version="1.2.9"/>
</config>
```

**/Mage/Mohit/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description.bottom" template="Mage_Mohit::product/list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="category.description.bottom" destination="page.main.title" before="category.product.list.additional"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

**/Mage/Mohit/view/frontend/templates/product/list.php**

```
<?php
    <button> 
        <span> 
            <?= __('New Button') ?> 
        </span> 
    </button>
?>
```

And finally apply this css this class :-

```
.page-main>.page-title-wrapper .page-title { display: flex; }
```

And after cache clean and check

[image]

This file code is you want to display button in catalog search page check code :-

**/Mage/Mohit/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="category.description.bottom" template="Mage_Mohit::product/list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="category.description.bottom" destination="page.main.title" before="-"/>

     </body>
</page>
```

And same apply css :-

```
.page-main>.page-title-wrapper .page-title { display: flex; }
```

[image]

Any Query let me know.

thanks.

Comment: thank , ill try this and let you know

Comment: Okay and helpful answer so accpet and upvote answer because helpful to other community... Thanks.

Comment: i tried to access it from `/catalogsearch/result/?q=wine` but the button does not show up

Comment: Hello @jojo Please check my update answer and helpful so accept and upvote answer because helpful to other community. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works